# Append file name to list comprehension

Tags: python-3.x, operating-system

Here is my code which finds .c files in directory. I want to append them to cfiles list comprehension. So I could access to them like cfiles[1], cfiles[2]...

```
for files in os.listdir(input_arg):
    if files.endswith(".c"):
        cfiles= [((os.path.abspath(input_arg)+"/"+files))]
```

This will just add first found item to cfiles. How should look the for loop in this case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming input_arg is already defined:

```
cfiles = [os.path.abspath(input_arg)+"/"+files for files in os.listdir(input_arg) if files.endswith(".c")]
```